# Raspberry Pi OpenCV + Yolo : to return true or false when detecting "person"

Tags: python, opencv, classification, object-detection, yolov4

I would like to use Raspberry Pi with OpenCV + yolo to do smart monitering system.

The question is: Instead of showing a box on the screen, could it return Ture or False when detecting "person"?

I learned that it could successful show on screen a box on screen when detecting something. I use a code from a chinese book, I am afraid that it might viloate the rule to paste the whole code here, so I breif describe the code it use.

the original code use the following 3 yolo file:

```
 yolo4-tiny.cfg
 coco.names
 yolo4-tine.weight
```

And

```
import cv2, numpy and time
```

the code resize the image to a smaller frame and then put the image into yolo

```
def XXX(image, model):
    classes, confs, boxes = model.detect(image, 0.6, 0.3)
    return classes, confs, boxes
```

the next step is show the box in the image.

```
def YYY(image, classes, confs, boxes, names, colors):
    new_image = image.copy()
    for (classid, conf, box) in zip(classes, confs, boxes):
        x, y, w , h = box 
        label = '{}: {:.2f}'.format(names[int(classid)], float(conf))
        color = colors[int(classid)]
        cv2.rectangle(new_image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
        cv2.putText(new_image, label, (x, y - 10), 
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, color, 2
        )
    return new_image
```

My question is how to return true when detecting "person". Thank you for respone this question.

Comment: it's as simple as : `if 0 in classes: return True`

Answer (score -1):

In your case, (I haven't used Yolo, but I've used OpenCV face detection and MTCNN), you can use one of the returned variables from the `detect()` function. It should be safe to assume that if the model creates a bounding box in the detection function, then a person exists.

```
def XXX(image, model):
    classes, confs, boxes = model.detect(image, 0.6, 0.3)
    return classes, confs, boxes

x, y, z = XXX(image, model)
if z is not None:  # if not an iterable
# if z.any():  # <-- this might be any(z) instead of z.any()
    # do something
```

Comment: "Python counts non-None variables as True by default" is wrong. See truthy and falsy values.

Comment: and you still need to test if any of the detections is classified as "person". there are more classes than just the one.

Comment: `[] is not None` => True, so that's really not doing what you hoped it would

Comment: Considering OP is using boxes directly as if it had already detected a person (look at their code) it working the same as if it found a person. That's not the same as if the nod found a person. OP's code is under the assumption that a found box will immediately get used. Therefore, if box contains values, it found something, according to OP's code.

Comment: `[] is not None`, you're right I mistyped that one.